# Programmatically check OpenGL support

Tags: java, opengl

My swing application is trying to use OpenGL to get better performance. But on some machines the UI doesnt load at all. How could i determine programmatically if OpenGl is supported so i could switch between xrenderer/OpenGL?

xrenderer works fine on all machines ive tested but id rather use OpenGL

This is what im using to enabled OpenGL

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","True");
```

This is what i get on the console:
"OpenGL pipeline enabled for default config on screen 1". I think this means that OpenGL is on, but the UI components wont load and the screen is white. I can still click on the invisible buttoms though.
[image: blankApp]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/hm2JfvM/blankApp.png))</sub>

EDIT: Sort of figured out the problem, OpenGL is enabled on screen 1 but not on screen 0. I dont know how to force it to be enabled on both 0 and 1. Disconnecting the second display caused OpenGL to bve enabled on screen 0, but this did not help and the app is still blank

Comment: Do you mean - system have video card  and OpenGL is physically accelerated  by GPU and not working on top of CPU i.e. Mesa CPU mode ? In most cases - you should not care about this if you are not using any 3D graphics, for example on Windows Java2D uses DirectDraw for acceleration instead of OpenGL.

Comment: @VictorGubin My GPU supports OpenGL, its just that on multi monitor setup i cannot figure out how to enable the OpenGL pipeline for both screens, the one where it is not enabled (screen 0 or 1) doesnt draw the UI at all. Im only using 2D graphics so i should skip on OpenGL then? I read elsewhere that enabling it improves drawing performance

Comment: Looks like you need to upgrade the graphical driver. I.e. install proprietary driver which supports multiple displays in the same time. I don't think this is a code issue.

Comment: @VictorGubin even if its not a code issue, how do i check this through code? I mean how am i supposed choose a renderer if i dont know what the user has installed?

Comment: This is actually not so trivial. You will need to use a direct OpenGL bindings to java like [lwjgl](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide), read the video card devices available etc.